# Where did my errors go for PhpStorm (mac)

Tags: php, phpstorm, intellij-inspections

- PhpStorm: 2021.2.2
- OS: Mac OSX Catalina

I am working in the latest version of PhpStorm, and let me give you a couple of examples as I am sure its a setting some where I need to turn on:

Consider this PHP function:

```
/**
 * Use rings.
 *
 * Only the character has rings.
 *
 * @param $attacker
 * @return array
 */
protected function useRings($attacker): array {
    ....
}
```

If I update this function to take another param, but do not update the dock blocks, PhpStorm use to have squiggly lines that when hovered would tell me my doc blocks needs to be updated.

If I didn't type hint the function, it would underline it and be like: whats the type hint?

Little things like this I seem to be missing. For context when I used PhpStorm on Ubuntu, this seemed built in and right out of the box. I loved it, but on mac, I am missing this functionality.

Thoughts?

Comment: Check your PHPDoc inspections in `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections` and ensure that `PHP -> PHPDoc` is enabled for `"PHPDoc comment matches function/method declaration"` and `Code style -> "PHPDoc comment signature is not complete"`. I would suggest exporting/comparing your settings and plugins from the Ubuntu version and import them to your Mac.

Comment: @WillB. Thank you :D